# How to pass arguments to phtml block?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml

I've updated the default breadcrumbs.phtml which now displays the company logo within the breadcrumb section, however I do not need the logo to show on category pages.

I have tried to update my catalog_category_view.xml to pass an argument to the block:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_logo" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </body>
</page>
```

and within my breadcrumbs.phtml I am trying to get the value of the show_logo by:

```
echo $this->getData('show_logo');
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working?

Can anyone please help me to understand why this isn't working and how I can get this to work so that I can check the argument so I can check whether to show the logo or not?

Thanks

Comment: You can easily check by current page, if current page is `catalog_category_view` then hide it

Comment: Hi Keyur, any advise on how to check the current page? Sorry, i'm new to magento development and haven't really got any clue on how to do anything at the moment :/

Comment: if you try the echo false its normal see anything

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the following method instead of:

```
$this->getShowLogo();
```

If you want to know the value, use `vardump()` or `print_r()`.Hope it help you!

Comment: $this->getData('show_logo') can you please explain why this won't work?

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV you should use `$this->getDataByKey('show_logo')`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mirko :)